# Only masking forward can surf the domain

Tags: masking

I have 2 domains let's say example.com and example.mynetwork.com
I am using parallels plesk webserver for main domain cpanel for subdomain
The subdomain example forward with masking to example.com can I make the website only work at example.mynetwork.com and if anyone visit the website example.com he redirect to example.mynetwork.com?

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: the main domain plesk .. the subdomain cpanel

Comment: Its probably a good idea to add that to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can reach transparent redirect(or masking as you said) with frames, place following HTML code into index.html on example.mynetwork.com:

```
<FRAMESET>
<FRAME SRC="http://example.com/" NORESIZE>
<NOFRAMES>
Your browser does not support frames.
</NOFRAMES>
</FRAMESET>
```

In case of simple redirect:
Here simple `index.php` which redirects visitors to http://example.mynetwork.com

```
<?php

header("Location: http://example.mynetwork.com/");
die();
```

Place this file into `/httpdocs` of example.com

Comment: but anway example.mynetwork redirect to example.com but with masking

Comment: You asking how to set up redirect from example.com to example.mynetwork.com, I'm right? If example.mynetwork.com redirects you back to example.com may be you have some settings for doing this?

Comment: the subdomain http://example.mynetwork.com forwarded to example.com
i want the user can't connect to example.com directly.. he must open this domain http://example.mynetwork.com and it will show him the website with masking.

Comment: Ok, I think i get you, please check answer, I've add frame forwarding example.